# Android: Alarm manager and Intent filters Not working

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

So I am setting an alarm which triggers an intent. I also have a broadcast listener which has an intentfilter to catch that intent but for some reason its not working. I am not sure where the problem lies (send or receive or both).

Sending Code:

```
Intent reminderIntent = new Intent();
reminderIntent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION_ALARM); //INTENT_ACTION_ALARM is String "intent_myaction_alarm"

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, reminderIntent, 0);

Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Receive Code:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(INTENT_ACTION_ALARM);

alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // DO SOMETHING
   } 
};

context.registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: did you register the Broadcast Receiver in the Manifest.xml? (edit: i posted an answer below if you didn't have the receiver in the manifest)

Comment: Please post your receiver code.

Comment: Sorry. The code is correct. There is no need to declare the reciever in the manifest since I am dynamically creating it and apply the intentFilter to it.

Comment: The problem was with some other part of my code which was broken.

Comment: Can you please share the problem and solution in your code? I have written the same code but not working.

Comment: @Tenfour04 can you please tell possible problems in triggering broadcast receiver.